# Debian grub2 update removed Windows boot option

Tags: windows-xp, debian, grub, multi-boot

Since I updated grub to grub 2 I no longer get the option to boot to Windows (which is unfortunately sometimes necessary for proprietary MSIE browser plugins I need to use for work).

Relevant `/boot/grub/menu.lst` portion:

```
### END DEBIAN AUTOMAGIC KERNELS LIST

# This is a divider, added to separate the menu items below from the Debian
# ones.
title           Other operating systems:
root


# This entry automatically added by the Debian installer for a non-linux OS
# on /dev/hda1
title           Windows NT/2000/XP
root            (hd0,0)
savedefault
makeactive
chainloader     +1
```

This however does not appear anymore. I do have some entries in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` with entries like these:

```
menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 2.6.32-5-amd64' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='(hd1,msdos1)'
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set e638c434-4884-412f-a141-2c194f881fae
        echo    'Loading Linux 2.6.32-5-amd64 ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-5-amd64 root=UUID=e638c434-4884-412f-a141-2c194f881fae ro  quiet
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-5-amd64
}
```

Do I have to alter that file? If so, what is the correct syntax for a Windows boot? If not, what could be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is based on for Ubuntu but it should be valid for Debian's grub2-package too:

`/boot/grub/grub.cfg` is overwritten each time you run `/usr/sbin/update-grub2` or when it's called after a kernel update. grub2 should have auto-detected the windows installation via `/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober` and added it to the boot menu. Howewer custom entries should be made in `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`

**Update:**

You could try to add the Windows Loader manually by adding the following to `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`:

```
menuentry "Windows on /dev/hda1" {
insmod ntfs
set root='(hd0,1)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set YOURUUID
chainloader +1
}
```

"YOURUUID" is the [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) of your Windows partition. You can get it by doing a `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/ | grep hda1`. After editing the file do a "sudo update-grub2" to generate a new grub.cfg.

It depends on `os-prober`, which may not be installed, in which case do a:

```
sudo apt-get install os-prober
```

... and run `sudo update-grub2` again.

Comment: `update-grub2` indeed creates a new configutaion file, `/etc/grub.d/30_os-orober` is there, but elas, no Windows entry as of yet, so it seems it cannot detect it for some reason. Could it be a hd is blacklisted somewhere? (/grasping at straws).

Comment: I don't know if there cold be a blacklisted hd. I'm still not really experienced with grub2. What output do you get from "sudo os-prober"?

Comment: Aha, that was it, although I had a `/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober`, it depended on the (quite obviously named) `os-prober` executable which wasn't on the system (and for some reason grub fails to provide even a simple error report about that). A simple install of that package and rerunning `update-grub2` did the trick, it's in  `grub.cfg` now, my thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Wrikken's solution also worked for me.  I'm regurgitating it in easy to follow directions.

**Step 1**

```
sudo apt-get install os-prober
```

This can be tested with:

```
sudo os-prober
```

Which, for me, gives the output:

```
/dev/sda1:Microsoft Windows XP Professional:Windows:chain
```

**Step 2**

```
sudo update-grub2
```

Comment: Ack., see my comment @ the 28th of september, this was indeed what solved it.

Comment: Maybe you can copy and paste my answer as your own (and then I can remove mine)?  I believe it is better if the solution is part of the answer instead of in the comments.