# Windows 7 partition disappeared from hard drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, debian, grub

I had a windows 7 and Debian 7 install and I've been using the computer fine for almost a year. A couple weeks ago I tried to load Windows and realized the boot option in grub was missing.

After [reading around](https://superuser.com/a/228442/29071) I tried `sudo update-grub2` and `sudo update-grub` but nether seems to recover the drive. I tried `os-probe` and `fdisk` but it seems the partition is missing.

Any ideas what I can do to recover my windows 7 install on this SSD hard drive?

I haven't made any partition changes or done anything I can remember that would have messed with the partition table.

```
user@localhost:~$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 120.0 GB, 120034123776 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 14593 cylinders, total 234441648 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000535e8

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   224860159   112429056   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       224862206   234440703     4789249    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       224862208   234440703     4789248   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

I'm pretty sure the windows 7 partion was over 30GB.

Comment: All the sectors of the disk are used by the partitions listed by fdisk... from 2048 to almost last, without hole. So I think there is no other partition on this disk anymore. This is not Debian or grub that can't access or mount it, there is no other partition (and no space to have one). Are you sure you have only 1 disk?

Comment: Yes, it's just a single SSD inside a laptop.

Comment: Can you try booting into Windows recovery mode with a Windows disk and see if it gives you the option to restore the system? If it doesn't then I am afraid this is going to be very difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk).

Try following their [step-by-step guide](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step) and see if you can find your lost partition using that.

Make sure you [backup your current partition table](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y2l1lU1OQUk) before you make any changes to it, in case something goes horribly wrong and you wish to revert back to your old partition table.

EDIT: TestDisk might come pre-installed on your system. If not, you could install it using

```
aptitude install testdisk
```

Alternatively, you could use a [LiveCD with TestDisk pre-installed](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Livecd).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe partition still exists, but Debian can't mount it, or something was messed in MBR.
Try booting from Windows LiveCD/DVD/USB, or plug your drive to another computer which runs Windows.
Then use `diskmgmt.msc` on that computer (press Win+R -> discmgmt.msc),
or use partition tools (such as Partition Magic, [Acronis](http://www.acronis.com) tools) to find/recover/work with partitions.
And after you recover the partition, you can use tools like [EasyBSD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) to make computer load your Windows.